# How to get value of out variable of PL/SQL procedure called in unix bash shell script

Tags: unix

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sqlplus -s user@lnpfvd1.world/password<<!

   declare 

   var_truc_result VARCHAR2(255);

   begin 

   brr_truncate_generic_procedure('TABLE_NAME', var_truc_result);

   end;
/
!
```

We are calling `brr_truncate_generic_procedure` which sets some value(Success/Failure) inside out variable `var_truc_result`.

We just want to take this variable in unix shell variable so that we can put some logic on basis of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant test this myself at the moment, but something like this should work:

```
result=`sqlplus / <<SCRIPT| grep ^result | sed "s/^result: //"
set serveroutput on
declare
    var_truc_result VARCHAR2(255);
begin
   brr_truncate_generic_procedure('TABLE_NAME', var_truc_result);
   dbms_output.put_line( 'result: ' || var_truc_result);
end;
/
exit
SCRIPT`

echo var_truc_result is: $result
```

You could also try

```
select var_truc_result as "answer"
from dual
```

in place of the dbms_output line, but you'll need to tweak the grep/sed

**Edit:**

I found [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:430819636473) discussion on AskTom which offers some variations etc on the above, which may help too

Comment: ok - if you run that block outside of a script do you get any output from dbms_output.put_line? ie if you run it in sqlplus for example?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake . There was error in procedure . Its now working fine Thanks.